# Use the same ControllerAdvice in a parent module of a microservice architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, microservices, controller-advice

Is it considered as a best practise if we put the same controllerAdvice in the parent project of our microservice architecture. In fact we can throw only two runtime exceptions (FunctionalException and TechnicalException). Both of them are also in a common parent project. Moreover, we have the same respone model in case of errors.